# Converting float to BigDecimal then back to float

Tags: java, android, floating-point, bigdecimal

I am trying to convert a float to BigDecimal then do some maths. After that i would require the final results in Float.

From what I known, the only safe way to get a float to become a BigDecimal number is to use the string constructor.

I have two approaches but both didnt work. Both gives me an additional 0.000001 value

Approach #1:

```
Float num1 = 13.846154f;
BigDecimal calculation = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(num1));
BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal("2.0").add(calculation);

Float finalResults = num2.floatValue();
```

Approach #2:

```
Float num1 = 13.846154f;
BigDecimal calculation = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(num1));
BigDecimal num2 = new BigDecimal("2.0").add(calculation);

Float finalResults = Float.parseFloat(num2.toString());
```

Is there a way to safely do the math and not lose precision when i convert the number back to float?

Edit #1
I did some testing and found something weird.

Float original = 13.846154f;

```
BigDecimal originalNum = new BigDecimal(Float.valueOf(original));

BigDecimal numTwo = new BigDecimal("14.0"); 
BigDecimal numThree = new BigDecimal("20.0");
BigDecimal numFour = new BigDecimal("30.0");

numTwo = numTwo.add(originalNum);
numThree = numThree.add(originalNum);
numFour = numFour.add(originalNum);
```

It is still adding that extra 0.000001..

Comment: have you tried printing out the result of Float.toString(num1) to ensure what you're feeding into the BigDecimal constructor is what you think it is?

Comment: You can't pass a `float` or a `Float` to `BigDecimal#add`.

Comment: @rgettman I think OP meant sth else, check my edit please.

Comment: good catch! @rgettman is right, you are passing float 'num1' to your add operation, not the BD representation of the float 'maths'

Comment: @Juvanis Only the OP can comment on whether `add(maths)` was the real intention.

Comment: With `add(maths)`, I am getting `15.846154` with both approaches.

Comment: @rgettman in some sense, yes. but in this case it is obvious that s/he intended to type add(maths)!! otherwise it would be non-referred variable.

Comment: @DavidDaedalus Yes the result is correct.

Comment: @rgettman how do i go about doing it?

Comment: have you seen this? it seems germane

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749615/losing-precision-converting-from-java-bigdecimal-to-double

Comment: specifically - the bit about changing BDs rounding mode...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid losing any precision, you have to use BigDeciml all the way, using a little bit of BigDecimal is likely to be pointless.

I suggest using `double`, it has one billion times the accuracy (Really it is ~10^9 *)

If you are going to use `float` don't use `Float` as this just adds overhead for no benefit.

If you do `13.846154` this is already more precision than `float` supports.

```
System.out.println(13.846155f);
System.out.println(23.846155f);
System.out.println(33.846155f);
```

prints

```
13.846155
23.846155
33.846153 <- a representation error with this many digits.
```

Instead I suggest you try

```
double finalResult = 13.846154 + 2.0;
```

btw

```
 System.out.println(13.846154+ 2.0);
```

prints

```
 15.846154
```

Comment: Is there a way to cast BigDecimal back to float? I need float because im actually using a method that takes in float..

Comment: @thhVictor In that case, just use a `float` all the way.  Using a `Float` or a `BigDecimal` won't help as `float` isn't very accurate.  To answer your question, you can use BigDecimal.floatValue() to extract the nearest representable values as a `float`

Answer (score 2):

The `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor is exact, as is the conversion from `float` to `double`, so if you start with a `float` value `num1`, `new BigDecimal(num1)` will give the exact `BigDecimal` equivalent.

It may not be quite what you expect. For example, the closest `float` to 13.846154 is 13.84615421295166015625, so that is the initial value of `num1` and of `calculation`.

The `BigDecimal` addition of 2 is exact, giving 15.84615421295166015625.

The next problem is turning it into a `float` for further calculation. As it happens, it is exactly representable as a `float`, so there is no further loss of precision. In general, converting a `BigDecimal` to `float` will involve rounding to the nearest `float`.

It turns out that all the loss of precision in this calculation happened on the initialization of `num1`. If you do it this way, without all the conversions to and from String, you will get as close as you can, given initial use of `float`.

If `float` is not precise enough for your calculations, but you need a `float` to pass to another method, consider using either `BigDecimal` or `double` for the whole calculation except for the final step. `BigDecimal`'s `floatValue()` does return the closest `float` to the exact value of the `BigDecimal`.

There is one case in which it is advantageous to use `String`. If you know you want a BigDecimal to be an exact decimal fraction, constructing the `BigDecimal` from the String representation of the fraction gets it exactly. Writing something like `new BigDecimal(1.0)` gets a `BigDecimal` whose value is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, the value of the closest double to 0.1. If you have already converted to `float` or `double`, converting via `String` will either make no difference or cause loss of precision. It will not help.

Comment: I have read a post somewhere saying using string will prevent all the precision loss by using BigDecimal addition method. However, what i require is to input a float number and do the calculate in BigDecimal then return me float. Is there a way you would suggest me doing so?

Comment: Note that there are calculations that cannot be done exactly in BigDecimal. For example, one third cannot be represented exactly. If your calculations are all exactly representable in finite decimal fractions, use BigDecimal, and take its floatValue when you need the closest float.

Comment: Then is there a way for me to do maths in java without losing precision?

Comment: Not in all cases. Ultimately, there is no way to map all the real numbers to any finite length representation. Can you be specific about the calculations you need to do? That would help in selecting the best approach. The choices include double, which supports greater precision than the most accurate physical measurement that has ever been done, BigDecimal that can exactly represent every short decimal fraction, and rational number packages that can exactly represent any ratio of integers.

Comment: I am getting my data from a build in method that returns the data in float and I am trying to calculate the results then return the results in float. The only way i saw was convert the float to BigDecimal via string constructor then do the calculation. After that I would have to convert the BigDecimal back to float so I can parse the data back to another method which takes in float as well.

Comment: If you are getting a float, transforming it, and then passing the result as a float, forget the idea of perfect accuracy. Short decimal fractions have no particular significance, so BigDecimal is irrelevant. The only question is whether float is precise enough for your intermediate results, or should you use double. I tend to use double on general principles.

Comment: As I already pointed out, you can get the exact value of a float as a BigDecimal by using the BigDecimal(double) constructor. Conversion to String may cause rounding.