# Is there a way to get right results from BigDecimal.floatValue() function?

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal

I came accross a code snippet:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(454756.43);
float number = bigDecimal.floatValue();
System.out.println(number);
```

The result is: 454756.44

So basically I am trying to understand how to get the correct result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [losing precision converting from java BigDecimal to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749615/losing-precision-converting-from-java-bigdecimal-to-double)

Comment: What is a correct result in your opinion? And why?

Comment: Is there a way on how to get 454756.43 because that i think it should be right. If its wrong in your opinion please tell me why as i am still learning java this can help me with learning.

Comment: float doesn't have enough precision to represent that number so it rounds it to the nearest possible. If you just want to print the number, use `bigDecimal.toString()`. If you actually want to use the number and care precision, then you have to work on `bigDecimal` itself, without extracting float from it.